# replacing audio of a clip after editing on a timeline in Premier Pro CC 2017

Tags: premiere

I have a clip which I have edited on a timeline, I want to go back to merging a new audio file into the original file. I try merging the audio file into the original file but this creates a new merged clip which does not have the edits.

Comment: What do you mean by merged clip? Could you outline the steps you've tried? Maybe include some screenshots of your timeline or export window?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to replace the source of the clip in question with the timeline that has the changed audio.  There should be a "Replace Footage" option or something like that.  I'm only familiar with CS6 though, so I'm a bit out of date on exact specifics in the latest version of CC.

Answer (score 1):

The steps I took:
 - merge good audio with video clip
 - create new sequence and add the new merged audio/video clip
 - export video
 - "Replace footage" of the original video
 - all your edits are now kept and the audio should have changed as well